# DuplicatePropertyError: Class class_name already has property property_name

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm developing for GAE-Python 2.7 on Mac using Eclipse + PyDev and, since the SDK 1.7.6 (where the new dev_appserver was introduced), I'm having a "DuplicatePropertyError" 4 out of 5 times (on average) when executing the first request. Also, even if the first request goes fine, the error might appear in later requests.

This error is only happening in development (in production everything goes fine) and prior to 1.7.6 I never had this.

I didn't pay too much attention to this problem because, so far, I was using the old_dev_appserver in order to be able to continue debugging my app (Google broke support to pydevd by using stdin/stdout for ipc in the new dev server). However, since the old dev server will be dropped from July 1st, I think it's time to start using the new one :-).

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? Any solution/workaround?

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 515, in __init__
_initialize_properties(cls, name, bases, dct)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 430, in _initialize_properties
attr.__property_config__(model_class, attr_name)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3686, in __property_config__
self.collection_name))
DuplicatePropertyError: Class Organization already has property wagesheetrow_set 
INFO     2013-06-07 15:13:54,864 server.py:585] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Do you have two ReferenceProperty fields from Organization to WageSheetRow, perhaps?

Comment: No, I don't. I forgot to mention that the pair class-property raising the error is not always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out! Apparently the error is coming when creating a ReferenceProperty without giving it an explicit collection_name.

For example, this might trigger the error:

```
class WageSheetRow(db.Model):
    organization = db.ReferenceProperty(Organization)
```

and this is the correct way:

```
class WageSheetRow(db.Model):
    organization = db.ReferenceProperty(Organization, collection_name='aName')
```

This never happened before with the old server but, apparently, the new server (1.7.6+) has changed the way of initialising instances.

It's also to mention that exactly the same code might trigger the error in one specific machine, but not in another one running exactly the same piece of code.

Comment: I got this error when I added a ReferenceProperty without a collection, but only after changing the property name. so on some class `Foo` I started with `bar = db.ReferenceProperty()` which worked, then I changed it to: `baz = db.ReferenceProperty()` and redeployed, after which instances starting throwing at initialization. Woops!